# Vertically centering the text in a table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

So I have a table like:

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{tabular}{C{3cm}C{2.3cm}C{2.3cm}C{2.3cm}}

 & \textbf{Case 1}  & \textbf{Case 2} & \textbf{Case 3} \\

\textbf{Scenario 1}& \cellcolor[HTML]{158B00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55AA00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{95CA00}         \\ [2.3cm]       


\textbf{Scenario 2}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{008000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{40A000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{80C000} \\[2.3cm]
%\multicolumn{1}{l!{\color{red}\vrule width 4pt}}{\cellcolor[HTML]{80C000}}      \\[2.3cm]

\textbf{Scenario 3}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{40a000}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55aa00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{6ab500} \\[2.3cm]

\end{tabular}
```

I want to vertically center the **Scenario 1, Scenario 2, Scenario 3**, but failed with many methods such as **m**. Is this because of the defined parameters of the table? Any idea how could I do that?

Comment: you are using capital C it should be small c -- unless you are defining something new

Comment: Sorry I attached the right line of defiining C. It is not the small c. That does not work.

Comment: have a look at the answer

Comment: Your problem is consequence that you terminate each row with `\\[2.3cm]`. So far your colored cells are empty, however, if you will add some text in it, you will have 2.3 cm height vertical space after text in those cells. If you will remove `[2.3cm]` after each row termination, vertical centering will work as expected, however, cells' heights will be reduce to the text height in cells in the first column or to height of text in colored cells. Please, clarify, what is the real problem.

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie  please see the square answer below in edit

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie did the answer meet your requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[!h]
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{ #1}}
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}p{2.3cm}}

    &\mc{ \textbf{Case 1}}  & \mc{\textbf{Case 2}} & \mc{\textbf{Case 3}} \\

    \textbf{Scenario 1}& \cellcolor[HTML]{158B00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55AA00} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{95CA00}         \\ [2.3cm]       


    \textbf{Scenario 2}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{008000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{40A000} & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{80C000} \\[2.3cm]
    %\multicolumn{1}{l!{\color{red}\vrule width 4pt}}{\cellcolor[HTML]{80C000}}      
   \\[2.3cm]

    \textbf{Scenario 3}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{40a000}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55aa00}  & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{6ab500} \\[2.3cm]

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

**EDIT --to redfine centering of the first column contents**

[image]

AS you could guess the m type column does not have effect because of the manual addition of 2.3cm at the end of the row-- so I added a rule in the first column which is not visible but centering now takes effect-- this can be seen by the second rule at the end of the row in black a vertical rule has been added -- this can be removed later on its only for demo purposes-- now the first column is centered and the 2.3cm can be removed--you can extend the rule in the first column to your choice

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}  

\begin{table}[!h]

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{ #1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3cm} }
\newcommand{\myrule}{\vrule width 3pt}

\begin{tabular}{ CCCC}
                            &\mc{ \textbf{Case 1}}  & \mc{\textbf{Case 2}} & 
                            \mc{\textbf{Case 3}} \myrule\\

\rule[-20pt]{0pt}{46pt} Scenario 1& \cellcolor[HTML]{158B00}  & 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{55AA00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{95CA00}      \myrule   \\      


    Scenario 2  & \cellcolor[HTML]{008000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{40A000} & 
   \cellcolor[HTML]{80C000} \\[2.3cm]

    Scenario 3  & \cellcolor[HTML]{40a000}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55aa00}  & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{6ab500} \\[2.3cm]

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

---

**FINAL RESULT**

```
\begin{tabular}{ CCCC}
                            &\mc{ \textbf{Case 1}}  & \mc{\textbf{Case 2}} & 
                            \mc{\textbf{Case 3}} \\

\rule[-27pt]{0pt}{70pt} Scenario 1& \cellcolor[HTML]{158B00}  & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{55AA00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{95CA00} \\      


\rule[-27pt]{0pt}{70pt} Scenario 2  & \cellcolor[HTML]{008000} & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{40A000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{80C000} \\

\rule[-27pt]{0pt}{70pt} Scenario 3  & \cellcolor[HTML]{40a000}  & 
\cellcolor[HTML]{55aa00}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{6ab500} \\

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

**EDIT TO CATER FOR SQUARE CELLS**

The rule inserted in the first cell each column is extending 40 pts below baseleine and each character is approx 6pt --thus 40 belo+6+40 above would give total 86points which corresponds to  3.022cm-- seeing the width of each color cell as 3cm this would mean a square (approx) with a 0.022 difference

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\def\convertto#1#2{\strip@pt\dimexpr #2*65536/\number\dimexpr 1#1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \newdimen\mylength
    \mylength=86pt
    \convertto{cm}{\the\mylength} cm
\begin{table}[!h]

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{ #1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{3cm} }
%\newcommand{\myrule}{\vrule width 3pt}

\begin{tabular}{ CCCC}
                            &\mc{ \textbf{Case 1}}  & \mc{\textbf{Case 2}} & 
                            \mc{\textbf{Case 3}} \\

\rule[-40pt]{0pt}{86pt} Scenario 1& \cellcolor[HTML]{158B00}  & 
  \cellcolor[HTML]{55AA00} & \cellcolor[HTML]{95CA00}       \\      

  \rule[-40pt]{0pt}{86pt}  Scenario 2  & \cellcolor[HTML]{008000} & \cellcolor[HTML]{40A000} & 
   \cellcolor[HTML]{80C000} \\[2.3cm]

   \rule[-40pt]{0pt}{86pt} Scenario 3  & \cellcolor[HTML]{40a000}  & \cellcolor[HTML]{55aa00}  & 
    \cellcolor[HTML]{6ab500} \\[2.3cm]

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: But the scenario 1, 2, 3 haven't vertically centered.

Comment: forgot the scenario in correcting the table-- will do

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: please have a look now

Comment: I am working on it. I made it 2.3cm is to make sure the table cell with color to be square. This makes it a rectangle. How could I change it back to square?

Comment: the  width of 3cm is adjustable as is the height of the rule

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not mark it this late, not being home today.